# How to design below format in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a requirement in Android where I have to design four buttons as shown in Image below. I am not sure which Layout should I use and how to make it happen where 60-40% ratio will be resizable across all screens. Thankyou!

[image]

Comment: You can also use LinearLayout with weight or [PercentLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

Comment: add about what have you tried so far and where you are actually struck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After drag and drop, without any alterations to `layout_width` and `layout_height`

```
LinearLayout (Vertical)
    LinearLayout (Horizontal) //layout_weight: 0.4
       FrameLayout //layout_weight: 0.4
       FrameLayout //layout_weight: 0.6
    LinearLayout (Horizontal) //layout_weight: 0.6
       FrameLayout //layout_weight: 0.6
       FrameLayout //layout_weight: 0.4
```

> NOTE: If you change `match_parent` to `0dp`, you shall have the weights in the right places as in 0.6 for 60% and 0.4 for 40%.

[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="#d00000"></FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="#9be412" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:background="#12b9a3" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="#b208a7" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make your layout relative by using the weight attribute. I provided an example suiting your case. Note that the weight sum in this example is always 1.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@color/red"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="@color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="@color/green"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@color/orange"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: *Note that the weight sum always is 1.* that is not true. Also note that nested weights are bad for performance

Comment: I meant in this example. I'll adjust it.

Comment: @Zeke this is not true. 0.4 will occupy 40% and 0.6 will occupy 60%

Comment: true if height is 0dp and false if match parent. True for your answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Using 3 Linear Layout. First Linear layout will be vertical and weigthSum=2  with 2 Linear Layout children and their weight be 1 and each child linear layout will be horizontal and have 2 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use percent support library to your project.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:xx.x.x'
}
```

---

```
 <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ff44aacc"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="70%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/top_left"
        android:background="#ffe40000"
        app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="30%" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_left"
        android:background="#ff00ff22"
        app:layout_heightPercent="80%" />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:layout_weight="60"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:layout_weight="40"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:layout_weight="40"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:layout_weight="60"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks...